# JQuery line numbers on Textarea with wrapping support

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am working on a textarea with line numbers. Now I found a great little script. http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/

Demo here: http://jakiestfu.github.io/Behave.js/examples/example-hook-linenums.html

The one feature I am missing is the ability to enable line wrapping.

Of course I can add `wrap="on"` to the textarea, and that indeed offers wrapping, but the line numbers are then messed up.

Any idea how I could add support for wrapping whist keeping the line numbers correct?

Comment: Did you realize, that the         BehaveHooks.add(['keydown'], function(data){         is never invoked?

Comment: The line numbers are messed up from a CSS-point of view here. Try 'float:right' for the textarea and 'float:left; width:20px; position:relative;' for div.line-nums

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't produce the desired effect. When wrap is on, and more text is entered on 1 line than fits in the textarea, the text continues below, but it instantly adds another line number on the place of the 2nd part of the first line, the moment you hit enter. Example: http://i.imgur.com/wMONnF2.png just 2 lines really

Comment: The CSS in my second comment was only for the gray line numbers-box on the left. Your main problem (I think) is, that this keydownFunction is never called. (at least in my Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="keyDown()">

<div class="container" style="width:300px;">
    <div id="numbers" style="float:left; background:gray; width:20px;"></div>
    <textarea onkeypress="keyDown()" rows="1" style="line-height:20px; display:block; float:right; overflow:hidden;" id="ta"></textarea>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function keyDown(){         
        var taLineHeight = 20; // This should match the line-height in the CSS
        var taHeight = ta.scrollHeight; // Get the scroll height of the textarea
        ta.style.height = taHeight + "px"; // This line is optional, I included it so you can more easily count the lines in an expanded textarea
        var numberOfLines = Math.floor(taHeight/taLineHeight);
        var inner= "";
        for(var i=1; i<=numberOfLines; i++)
            inner += "<div>"+i+"</div>";
        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = inner;           
    }       
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but this isn't producing the results I'm afraid :( https://jsfiddle.net/hs5pnsnd/ Also I want it to work with Behave.js. The function is called (in chrome at least), its just that the way the script is made, it wont support the wrapping I need.